# Android: View.getTag/setTag and IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android

Yes, I know you need a unique resource id when calling the version of these functions that requires a key, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create a resource id that can be used in this way. A final variable in my class wont work and neither will a hard coded value. Both threw an IllegalArgumentException. So what gives, how do you use these methods?

Spara

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> The specified key should be an id *declared in the resources* of the application to ensure it is unique.

So you can't just make up values and place them in a local variable.

Every resource you create whether it's a string (`R.string.*`), or a layout (`R.layout.*`) or an individual `View` (`R.id.*`) can have an ID.  This is something you must be doing already.

If you do need to store multiple objects against a single `View`, then you need to use the `R.id` variant as a key, like `someView.setKey(R.id.my_key_1, someObject)`.

Comment: Also, note that I got complaints from the core Android team for using the indexed form of `getTag()` and `setTag()`. Those are designed to be used by libraries or other reusable components (which cannot blindly call the regular `getTag()`/`setTag()` because they might conflict with the reuser of the code). If you are writing such a library, you're fine. If you are writing an ordinary Android application, use the regular non-indexed `getTag()`/`setTag()` methods, just with a collection of some form (e.g., `HashMap`) if you need to hold more than one value.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds reasonable. I hadn't even heard of the indexed version before and couldn't think of any particular reason to have multiple objects stored per view.

Comment: The correct way to use the indexed version of getTag()/setTag() is to use resource ids, as in R.id. Do not use R.string or R.layout as keys.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare. For some reason I had only thought of the get/setTag functions as one tag = one value. Using setTag with an object which itself contains multiple values will work perfectly.

Comment: @CommonsWare - if here are such complaints from the core Android team, it'd be great if it were added to the documentation.

Answer (score 44):

To create resource ID, which can be used identically to the ones you set within XML (with `@+id`), add

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="myId"/>
</resources>
```

in XML in `res/values/`.

Comment: For example: create /res/values/ids.xml and import you.package.R;

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item name="TAG_ONLINE_ID" type="id"/>
</resources>
```